# Google map not show in Bottom navigation with Activities in Andriod studio (java)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, bottomnavigationview

There is a GOOGLE icon in the lower left corner but the map is not displayed.

(1) strings.xml

(I write api in there)

> This api can be used, I also use the same set of api in other projects, but it can’t be displayed if I add it here.

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">HIKING</string>
<string name="map_key" translatable="false">AIza.....</string>
```

(2) AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/map_key" />
```

(3)activity_main.xml  (use RelativeLayout)

```
//navigation
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

and this is about map.

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/google_map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

(4)MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    //navigation
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.map);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.map:
                    return true;

                case R.id.mountains:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                            ,Mountain.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    return true;

                case R.id.watch:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                            , Watch.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    return true;

                case R.id.account:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                            ,Account.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

and more code.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap Map) {
    googleMap = Map;

    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            //set latitude and longitudue on marker
            markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude+" : "+latLng.longitude);
            googleMap.clear();
            //zoom on marker
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,10));
            //add marker on map
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Have you checked if you have enabled [Maps SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/overview)? Are you getting any error logs?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled the  Maps SDK for Android and there is no error code. I also tried to open a new project and put it in the same API. The map can be displayed. I don't know why it can't be displayed as long as it is in a project with Buttom Navigation.

Comment: Have you added restrictions to your API key? Do have an open billing account? The best way to know why the map is not being displayed is to contact Google Maps Platform support:  https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#creating-a-support-case